# Float navigation to the right side of the logo

Tags: html, css, menu, css-float

I have a logo on top left of my website. And I'm trying to put navigation menu vertically aligned to the right side of the logo. But it always appear at the bottom of the logo. I tried `float:left`.

I guess it's a simple thing but I can't do it. I may need a wrapper. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```css
.logo {}

#topnav {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-table;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" width="250" height="120" /></a>


    <div class="topnav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/fiap/">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are some issues with your markup that you should be aware of.
Your nesting is off (unless you want everything to be inside the logo div) and the container closing div is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it simply by adding `float: left` to logo class like that: http://jsfiddle.net/dssHf/
I has also restructured your HTML code because it was been invalid.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x120" alt="" /></a></div>  

    <div class="topnav"> 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/fiap/">Photos</a></li>        
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    clear: both;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;

}
.topnav {
    margin-left: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.logo` to this:

```
.logo img {
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87KCt/4/

CSS is cascading style sheets. That means a few things but here cascading means that the styles for class `.logo` cascade into `img` tags only.